# gets() function behaviour

Tags: c++, string, gets

In this code snippet:

```
char name[25];
int a;
cout<<"Enter number: ";
cin>>a;
cout<<"Enter name: ";
gets(name);
```

before I can even give the string name[] any value, it automatically skips it.
But when I alter the code and put the string input before the integer input,

```
char name[25];
int a;
cout<<"Enter name: ";
gets(name); 
cout<<"Enter number: ";
cin>>a;
```

it works perfectly. Why is the behavior of the gets() function so?
Any other string stream funtions that I can use as alternative to it?

Comment: Do note that `gets` is on its way out the door in C++ and has already left C.  You should just not use it or worry about it.

Comment: In the first case I assume you are pressing return/enter after entering a number which is then taken as the input for name.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'd argue that it's aready out (it's not in C++14)

Comment: I think that the gets() is reading '\n' as its input.

Comment: @krzaq So it is.  I thought it was a change to C++17 but looks like they did it in C++14.  Woot \o/

Comment: so how to overcome it?

Comment: use `getline` and `operator >>` and watch out for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: someone used  `cin.get()` to empty buffer. How does that work?